# Find the general solution of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, determinant

> $$\begin{cases}(2i)z+(i-1)w=-2\\(2+i)z+(1+i)w=1+4i\end{cases}$$
>
> How to solve this linear system over $\mathbb{C}$?

---

what I did :

let $$z=x+iy$$

$$w=x'+iy'$$

so we get :

$$(2i)(x+iy)+(i-1)(x'+y'i)=-2\implies(-2y+x'-y')+(2x+x'-y')i=-2$$
$$(2+i)(x+iy)+(1+i)(x'+y'i)=1+4i\implies(2x-y+x'-y')+(x+y+x'+y')i=-1+4i$$

so i need to solve this linear system:

$$\begin{cases}-2y+x'-y'=-2\\2x+x'-y'=0\\2x-y+x'-y'=-1\\x+y+x'+y'=4\end{cases}$$

and find the general solution for it ...

Is this a correct way to solve it , if not any other idea how to solve it ?

Comment: That's a correct way to do it. I did spot a calculation error in both lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Delta=(2i(1+i)-(2+i)(i-1)=1+i$$
$$\Delta_z=-2(1+i)-(1+4i)(i-1)=3+i$$ and
$$\Delta_w=2i(1+4i)-(2+i)(-2)=-4+4i,$$
which gives $$w=\frac{\Delta_w}{\Delta}=4i$$ and $$z=\frac{\Delta_z}{\Delta}=2-i.$$

Comment: Cramer's rule, great!

Answer (score 1):

It is a *very* bad idea to express every complex number as $x+yi$ here. It follows from the first equation that $z+\frac{i-1}{2i}w=-\frac2{2i}$. Simplify this, express $z$ as a multiple of $w$ and replace the $z$ of the second equation by this value to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  eliminate $\,w\,$ between the equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
(2i)z+(i-1)w &=-2 &\mid \;\cdot\, (1+i)
 \\(2+i)z+(1+i)w&=1+4i &\mid \;\cdot\, (i-1)
\end{align}
\end{cases} \quad \Bigg| \;-\; \Bigg|
$$

$$
\implies \quad \big(2i(1+i) - (2+i)(i-1)\big)z = -2(1+i) - (i-1)(1+4i) \;\;\iff\;\; (1+i)z=3+i
$$